# VBA QueryTables loops class reference

Tags: vba, excel, loops, excel-web-query

What I am trying to do is grab data form mutable URLs, at the same time using cells A1 to A10 as the last string of text on the URLs QueryTables.

- Example
  Cell A1= B0006SH4PA
- URL or QueryTables would changed in reference to cells text

  myURlocation=B0006SH4PA ' then data scraped from this URL then loop to next cell down
- This would continue to cell A10 with each cell having different test making a different QueryTable for every cell.

This is code I have at the moment

```
Sub URL_Static_Query()
Dim i As Integer
   
   With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
      "URL;myURlocation=" & Range("a1"), _
         Destination:=Range("a1"))
   
      .BackgroundQuery = True
      .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
      .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
      .SaveData = True
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So what's the outcome of your code? And why do you set the `Destination` to overwrite your data in the `A` column?

Comment: it only pulls data from one URL, I need it to pull it from mutable  URLs looping through each cell a1 to a10 as the last string of text

Comment: You are right is will override with my reference. Sorry QueryTables is very new to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it will write the data starting from column B below each other.

```
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 1 To 10
     With Sheet1.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;myURlocation=" & Range("a" & i), _
        Destination:=sheet1.Range("b999999").End(xlUp).Offset(1))

        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .SaveData = True
     End With
  Next i
```

Comment: It worked thank you so much ! I have a lot of tinkering to do with this!